# Class Literal vs Class.forname + Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, rtti

In the code snippet below, why does 1 not produce a run-time Exception as I am trying to cast Class>B> to Class>A>?

```
package example;

Class A {
   public A() {
   }
}

Class B extends A {
   public B() {
   }
}

public static void main() {

    Class<A> c = null;

    //1. Does not produce exception at run-time even though I cast Class<B> to Class<A>
    try {
        c = (Class<A>) Class.forName("example.B");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    }

    //2. Compile time error: Cannot Cast Class<B> to Class<A>
    c = (Class<A>) B.class; //Error
}
```

Comment: It *could* be throwing a ClassNotFoundException. With that exception handling, you would never know.

Comment: Oh I actually have a print inside the catch, just forgot to add it in my question. Rest assured there is no ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Class.forName()` returns `Class<?>`, which is roughly equivalent to `Class` (without generics).

The second version will also compile if you add another non-generic cast inbetween:

```
c = (Class<A>)(Class) B.class; // compiles
```

However, this can't be right, so the compiler saves you from this error. In the first version, it can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Because generics are only enforced by compiler not java virtual machine. You can think like ,  cleared by the compiler during compilation. Java generics are implemented in this way for backward compatibility with earlier java versions.

Answer (score 1):

Java generics are implemented by erasure, meaning that generics are checked at compile time, but are not available at runtime. This allows java code with generics to be backwards compatible with pre 1.5 code.